# Cron once in 2 days fails for months with 31 days

Tags: cron

I'm trying to write a cron expression that triggers *strictly* once in 2 days. By "strictly", I mean that the interval between 2 triggers should always be 2 days exactly.  This is what I have:

```
0 0 0 */2 * ? *
```

While this works fine for most cases, it fails for months with 31 days, such that it would run on 31st & then on 1st again.

I read on one of the posts that there's no way to get around this limitation. But I just wanted to check if somebody has solved this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about running it every day and track the actual last run date in a text file/database/etc?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more suitable for [ubuntu.se] or [su].

Comment: @KenWhite fwiw - I think the solution to this is scripting it into the job being run by cron, so not entirely off topic.

Comment: do you have an extra leading `0` by any chance? Otherwise `0` is not a valid Day of the Month. Also is the `?` allowed on other column besides the 1st 4?

Comment: @DanCornilescu: seems to be working fine. I'm testing it here - http://www.cronmaker.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with cron. However, conditioning your cron command would work like a charm :

```
0 0 0 * * [ <is my day odd?> ] && original_command
```

Now the problem is calculating whether a day is odd (or even, it doesn't matter). The best I could find is this : `$(( $(date +%s) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) % 2 ))`

It takes the number of seconds since Unix's epoch (01/01/1970 00:00:00) divide it into a numbers of days and takes its modulo 2, outputting 1 or 0, which are distinct valid input for `test`. However, dates are a hard problem and I would be surprised if I didn't overlook anything.

Comment: I didn't get it. Aren't we just doing the is-the-day-odd check twice here? How will that help here?

Comment: @mindreader no, you just need to prefix the original cron command with `[ $(( $(date +%s) / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ) % 2 )) ] &&`. My oddity check might work better than cron's month-of-the-day or than a year-of-the-day because it is based on the number of days since a definite date, Unix's epoch. Still not sure it's perfect though as I said. Also, you do a poor job of a mindreader ;)